# Where to download Firefox 4 and 5?

Tags: firefox

It seems [Firefox version numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Version_5.0) has suddenly accelerated to resemble that of Google Chrome.

Currently the Mozilla website offers for download the latest version 6.0.2, with the "[Older Downloads](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html)" section containing *only* version 3.6.22, with this note:

> Firefox 3.6.x will be maintained with security and stability updates
>   for a short amount of time.

As web developer who would like to make sure some applications and sites also work with Firefox 4 and 5, what would be a good place (as official as possible) to get those versions from?

Comment: I highly doubt you'll need to test those versions, like you said Firefox is imitating the chrome development cycle (and numbering scheme) and with that they took their automatic updating system, like you don't test with chrome 9 or 6 (current version is 13(!) if you didn't know) you aren't supposed to test those older versions since they were auto updated.

Comment: @Ziv: Good point; that may well be the best answer to this question (so consider posting it as answer too!). That's what I thought, sort of, but on the other hand I'm still used to thinking that a Firefox major version still "means something", and that perhaps there are many users who chose not to upgrade from e.g. Firefox 4 (I don't know how exactly the auto-updater works nowadays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla provides an ftp archive of old releases:

ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Specifically, the latest [firefox 4](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/4.0.1/) and [firefox 5](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/5.0.1/) as of posting.

These versions will auto-update if you don't disable it soon after install.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the correct answer. Thanks for the auto-update tip too.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the older versions here: http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Comment: Also, Firefox 3.6.x is the lts version of firefox and the other versions (4 and above) were automatically updated to the newer version.

Comment: Actually, if you take a look, there are no complete installers for Firefox 4 or 5 behind that link. (Only some kind of .mar update files for 5.0.1.)

Comment: Yeah, seems so... maybe that's because they don't want people to download these, due to their new version numbering? So the question is whether you would really need to test your sites against 4 and 5 anyway, if everybody is automatically upgraded to 6.

Comment: @BennyInc Corporate environments often disable auto-update features and lock on a version. Devs for that environment need to test that version.

Answer (score 1):

There are [all older firefox version here](http://www.oldapps.com/firefox.php), make your choice

Comment: +1. Windows only, but this site indeed has versions 4 & 5 available.

Comment: on the official Mozilla website you can download the Firefox 3.6 version on each OS. Perhaps with this version you are able to upgrade step by step on each version ?! I don't know

Comment: I doubt it - the upgrader probably takes you to latest (6.0.2 currently) automatically.

Comment: I think so, you may try

Answer (score -1):

Try here http://downloads.phpnuke.org/en/download-item-view-y-a-a-x-a/MOZILLA%2BFIREFOX.htm